# How do I paste into the second column of a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a macro for Microsoft Word 2007. The macro is supposed to make an n x 2 table and then insert one photo that was selected into every cell. Instead, it will put two photos per cell in the first column and none in the second column.

```
With Application.ActiveDocument    
    Dim myTable As Word.Table
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    ActiveWindow.View.TableGridlines = True
    Set myTable = .Tables.Add(Range:=myRange, NumRows:=Fix((Num / 2) + 0.5), NumColumns:=2)
        For I = 1 To Num
        oRow = Fix((I / 2) + 0.5) '
        If (I Mod 2) = 1 Then oCol = 1
        If (I Mod 2) = 0 Then oCol = 2
        myTable.Cell(oRow, oCol).Select
        Set pic = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=sDir(I), LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
            With pic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = InchesToPoints(2.25)
            .Width = InchesToPoints(3)
            End With
        Selection.Collapse
    Next
End With
```

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Step through line-by-line, examine in particular the values of variables `I`, `Num`, and `oCol`. I suspect you will find a problem with your logic, not a bad method/etc.

Comment: To debug this I've tried using a message box to determine the value of oCol before the the photos are added (which were correctly 1 and 2). I tried replacing "Set pic .InlineShapes.AddPicture...End with" "Selection.TypeText ("HI")" and every cell in every row and column had one "HI" inside of it.

Comment: In addition to that, I tried changing that to "Selection.TypeText(sDir(I))" and it had the appropriate path to the photos selected earlier in the sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
Dim tblCell as Word.Cell
```

Because it's usually easier to work with strongly typed variables, for readability and for intellisense:

```
Set tblCell = myTable.Cell(oRow, oCol)
Set pic = tblCell.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=sDir(I), LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        With pic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = InchesToPoints(2.25)
        .Width = InchesToPoints(3)
        End With
```

An explanation:

In your debugging, you did:

> I tried replacing "Set pic `.InlineShapes.AddPicture...End with` and `Selection.TypeText ("HI")`

Which should work, since you're working directly with the `Selection` to insert text. But as you had this qualified only to the `ActiveDocument` (you begin your code with `With ActiveDocument`)

```
.InlineShapes.AddPicture(...
```

Still it seems odd that the method you used originally did not work. When I did it in 2010, it puts ALL the pictures in the FIRST cell only.

Comment: This worked. Excellent. Thank you very much. I haven't had any formal training or education on this stuff so I'll have to do some research on "strongly typed values."

Comment: ah no worries. I just mean to use *more* variables instead of fewer -- especially to represent *parts of the object/file/etc.* that you want to work with in the code. Aside from ease of readability, you can then examine them in the Locals window in the VBE, which exposes all of their properties to you in a list/tree-view.  So it is very helpful when debugging. It may surprise you that I did not know the answer to your question until I started debugging it on my own :)

Comment: And if this has answered the question, do consider "Accepting" the answer.